# Is it possible to upload bigger files with Primefaces 6.0 FileUpload than Integer.MAX_VALUE bytes

Tags: file-upload, primefaces, weblogic, jsf-2.2

I have been playing around with the **FileUpload** component (**Primefaces version 6.0**), but have encountered a problem. I didn’t set any **sizeLimit** so I assumed there would be no size limit on the file. But when trying to upload files bigger than *2 147 483 647* bytes (Integer.**MAX_VALUE**) the upload just gets stuck (Internet Explorer throws the error **0x2efe** for the XMLHttpRequest).

I tried with the three following files:

File1 - *1 360 432 308* byte - **Works**

File2 - *2 133 808 256* byte - **Works**

File3 - *2 281 635 072* byte - **Gets stuck**

My question is:

Is it possible to use this **FileUpload** component to upload files bigger than *2 147 483 647* bytes (Integer.**MAX_VALUE**)? If it is, is it possible to limit it somehow to a max size bigger than *2 147 483 647* bytes (Integer.**MAX_VALUE**)?

Should probably mention we run Weblogic on the backend.

Comment: So you also tried Chrome or Firefox

Comment: I have also tried with Chrome to see if it is IE specific, but I get an error there too. The two error messages I get are "POST https://... net::ERR_CONNECTION_ABORTED" and "XHR failed loading: POST https://...".

Comment: Max Post Size in Weblogic console under Environment->Servers->"Server name"->Protocols->HTTP is set to -1, which means unlimited size according to the help text.

Comment: It seems I get the same error in also Primefaces version 6.1